# Using Zeit Now to build and deploy, how do I embed the Git commit SHA?

Tags: create-react-app, vercel

I have a Bitbucket repo which triggers Zeit Now to build and deploy my React project, created with creat-react-app. I simply granted Zeit and Bitbucket permission to talk to each other -so far so easy. Now I'm adding Sentry.io for error logging.

My aim is for the Git commit SHA to show up as the release name in Sentry for any errors.

So I want to [initialise Sentry](https://docs.sentry.io/workflow/releases/?platform=browser#configure-sdk) with the Git commit SHA, and [Zeit says](https://zeit.co/docs/v2/git-integrations/zeit-now-for-bitbucket#more-information-about-zeit-now-for-bitbucket) it provides a `BITBUCKET_COMMIT_SHA` to builds environment variable.

However, [create-react-app says](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/) that environment variables must start with `REACT_APP_`.

So I've made a `.env` file as per the [instructions to "expand" available environment variables](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/#expanding-environment-variables-in-env) and have ended up with

```
REACT_APP_BITBUCKET_COMMIT_SHA=${BITBUCKET_COMMIT_SHA}
```

To initialise Sentry I have

```
const releaseName = process.env.REACT_APP_BITBUCKET_COMMIT_SHA
Sentry.init({
    dsn: "https://123@sentry.io/123",
    release: 'projectName@' + releaseName
})
```

(I'll deal with `if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production')` later).

But the release name in Sentry just shows up as "undefined". What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Why not `process.env.BITBUCKET_COMMIT_SHA`?

Comment: @MartinZeitler create-react-app [says](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/) that environment variables must start with `REACT_APP_`. ("Any other variables except NODE_ENV will be ignored")

Answer (score 1):

Paulo from ZEIT kindly provided this answer -the trick is to put something like this in `package.json`:

```
"build": "REACT_APP_SHA=$BITBUCKET_COMMIT_SHA react-scripts build"
```